# $L^1(G)$ is a $C^*$-algebra $\iff$ $G$ is trivial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $L^1(G)$ be the group Banach $*$-algebra of a locally compact Hausdorff group $G$. Then it is known that $L^1(G)$ is a $C^*$-algebra if and only if the group $G$ is trivial.

The proof of this fact can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1255059/144766) and it is not elementary. To my surprise, I came across a seemingly much simpler and completely elementary proof in Vahid Shirbisheh's [Lectures on $C^*$-algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.3404.pdf), Proposition 2.2.21., Page 24.

However, upon more careful reading, I think that the proof is wrong. It goes like this:

Assume that $G$ is nontrivial and pick $s \in G\setminus \{1\}$. Pick an open relatively compact neighbourhood $U$ of $1$ in $G$ such that $U \cap sU = \emptyset$. Then by properties of left Haar measure we have $0 < \mu(U) < +\infty$. If we define
$$f : G \to \Bbb{C}, \quad f(x) := \frac1{\sqrt{\Delta(x)}}(\mathbf{1}_{U} - i \mathbf{1}_{sU})(x), \quad x \in G$$
it is easy to show that $f \in L^1(G)$, where $\Delta : G \to \langle0,+\infty\rangle$ is the modular function.

We have
\begin{align}
\|f * f^*\|_{L^1(G)} &= \int_G |(f * f^*)(x)|\,d\mu(x)\\
&=\int_G \left|\int_G f(y)\Delta(x^{-1}y)\overline{f(x^{-1}y)}\,d\mu(y)\right|d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \left|\int_G \Delta(x^{-1}y)\cdot \frac{\mathbf{1}_{U}(y) - i \mathbf{1}_{sU}(y)}{\sqrt{\Delta(y)}}\cdot \frac{\mathbf{1}_{U}(x^{-1}y) + i \mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y)}{\sqrt{\Delta(x^{-1}y)}}\,d\mu(y)\right|d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \frac1{\sqrt{\Delta(x)}} \left|\int_G (\mathbf{1}_U(y)\mathbf{1}_{U}(x^{-1}y) + i\mathbf{1}_U(y)\mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y) - i\mathbf{1}_U(x^{-1}y)\mathbf{1}_{sU}(y) + \mathbf{1}_{sU}(y)\mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y))\,d\mu(y)\right|d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \frac1{\sqrt{\Delta(x)}} \left|\mu(U \cap x U) + i \mu(U \cap xsU) - i\mu(xU \cap sU) + \mu(sU \cap xsU)\right|d\mu(x).
\end{align}

Now comes the dubious step. The author writes (paraphrased): "In the last integral each term of the integrand is non-zero at least for some values of $x\in G$ and when one of the terms is non-zero the other three terms are zero. This feature justifies the following steps of our argument:"

\begin{align}
\|f * f^*\|_{L^1(G)} &< \int_G \frac1{\sqrt{\Delta(x)}} (\mu(U \cap x U) +  \mu(U \cap xsU) +\mu(xU \cap sU) + \mu(sU \cap xsU))\,d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \frac1{\sqrt{\Delta(x)}} \left|\int_G (\mathbf{1}_U(y)\mathbf{1}_{U}(x^{-1}y) + \mathbf{1}_U(y)\mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y) + \mathbf{1}_U(x^{-1}y)\mathbf{1}_{sU}(y) + \mathbf{1}_{sU}(y)\mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y))\,d\mu(y)\right|d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \left(\int_G \Delta(x^{-1}y)\cdot \frac{\mathbf{1}_{U}(y) + \mathbf{1}_{sU}(y)}{\sqrt{\Delta(y)}}\cdot \frac{\mathbf{1}_{U}(x^{-1}y) + \mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y)}{\sqrt{\Delta(x^{-1}y)}}\,d\mu(y)\right)d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \left(\int_G \Delta(x^{-1}y)\cdot \left|\frac{\mathbf{1}_{U}(y) -i \mathbf{1}_{sU}(y)}{\sqrt{\Delta(y)}}\right|\cdot \left|\frac{\mathbf{1}_{U}(x^{-1}y) -i \mathbf{1}_{sU}(x^{-1}y)}{\sqrt{\Delta(x^{-1}y)}}\right|\,d\mu(y)\right)d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \left(\int_G \Delta(x^{-1}y)|f(y)||f(x^{-1}y)|\,d\mu(y)\right)d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_G \Delta(y)|f(y)|\left(\int_G |f(xy)|\,d\mu(x)\right)\,d\mu(y)\\
&= \int_G \Delta(y)|f(y)|\Delta(y^{-1})\left(\int_G |f(x)|\,d\mu(x)\right)\,d\mu(y)\\
&= \|f\|_{L^1(G)}^2.
\end{align}

So, the idea seems to be to notice that the supports of the functions
$$x \mapsto \mu(U \cap x U), \quad x \mapsto \mu(U \cap xsU), \quad x \mapsto \mu(xU \cap sU), \quad x \mapsto \mu(sU \cap xsU)$$
are pairwise disjoint and nonempty. Hence we somehow get the strict inequality, but I argue that it should in fact be equality. Precisely because the supports are pairwise disjoint we have
$$\left|\mu(U \cap x U) + i \mu(U \cap xsU) - i\mu(xU \cap sU) + \mu(sU \cap xsU)\right|=\mu(U \cap x U) +  \mu(U \cap xsU) +\mu(xU \cap sU) + \mu(sU \cap xsU)$$
for all $x \in G$. It is irrelevant that the supports are nonempty.

My questions are:

1. Is the proof indeed wrong?
2. If yes, can it be easily fixed?

Comment: Are the supports of these functions really disjoint? For example, if $x=1$ is the unit of $G$, then $\mu(U \cap xU) = \mu (U) \neq 0$ and $\mu(sU \cap xsU) = \mu(sU) \neq 0$. Or if $x \in G$ satisfies $x = x^{-1}$, then $\mu(U \cap xsU) = \mu (U \cap x^{-1}sU) = \mu(xU \cap sU)$.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets You are completely right. In fact, since the Haar measure has the property that every nonzero open set has positive measure, we have
\begin{align}
\{x \in G : \mu(U \cap xsU)> 0\,\text{  and  }\,\mu(xU \cap sU)> 0\} &= \{x \in G : U \cap xsU \ne \emptyset\,\text{  and  }\,xU \cap sU\ne \emptyset\}\\
&= \{x \in G : U \cap xsU \ne \emptyset\} \cap \{x \in G : xU \cap sU \ne \emptyset\}\\
&= \{x \in G : xsU \subseteq G\setminus U\}^c \cap \{x \in G : xU \subseteq G\setminus sU\}^c
\end{align}
which is an open set as an intersection of two open sets.

Comment: Therefore, we have
$$\left|\mu(U \cap x U) + i \mu(U \cap xsU) - i\mu(xU \cap sU) + \mu(sU \cap xsU)\right|<\mu(U \cap x U) +  \mu(U \cap xsU) +\mu(xU \cap sU) + \mu(sU \cap xsU)$$
on a nonempty open set so we have $<$ in the integrals as well. So the calculation as written is actually correct, but the explanation given by the author is wrong.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets Or maybe not, since it isn't that clear that there exists $x \in G$ such that $U \cap xsU \ne \emptyset$ and $U \cap x^{-1}sU \ne\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is wrong, and I don't think it can be easily fixed. If $G$ is discrete, we can take $U=\{e\}$ and the modular function is identically $1$, so that $f$ is just $\delta_e-i\delta_s$, which has $L^1$ norm $2$. Then $f\ast f^\ast=2\delta_e-i\delta_s+i\delta_{s^{-1}}$, which has $L^1$ norm $4$. So at least for this choice of $f$ there is no contradiction to the $C^\ast$-identity.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I need to find a different function $f \in L^1(G)$. Any ideas?

Comment: In the linked answer there is an example for $G=\mathbb Z$ with $3$ summands. I could imagine that something similar works in the general case with the Dirac deltas replaced by appropriate characteristic functions of open sets. But even if it does, one probably has to rule out some cases "by hand"